# Angular2 Re-enable submit button after it has been disabled in HTTP post request

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently doing a profile page for a website. There is a submit button at the bottom of the page. When user is viewing the page, the submit button is disabled as nothing has changed.

When something is modified and its valid, the button will be clickable. Then after submit through HTTP Post, if it is successful, there is a flag to make it unclickable, and a success message will be displayed for the user. Everything above this is fine.

However, the problem comes in when the user change the content again. Because there used to be a flag and the flag is always disabling the button.
So to solve the issue, i think there could be 2 approaches. One is to toggle the flag once the content is changed again. One is to Disable the button in a totally different fashion. But i am not sure how to do either of them.

TS code:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'profile', 
  templateUrl: 'profile.component.html',
})
export class ProfileComponent{
  name: string;
  email: string;
  updateSucc : boolean = false;
  profileForm : FormGroup;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private http:Http) { 

  this.profileForm = fb.group({
      'name' : ['', Validators.required],
      'email': [''],
    })

  submitForm(value: any){

   let form = {
       'updates': {
         'name' : value.name
       }  
     }

     let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
     let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers,
                                    withCredentials: true });

     this.http.post('http://SERVER.API?email='+localStorage.getItem('email'), form, options).subscribe(
        (res:any)=>{
           this.updateSucc = true;
           },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.backendService.checkLogIn(error.status);  
        }
      )
    }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Profile</h1>
  <div *ngIf = "updateSucc" class="alert alert-success">
    Update successful!
  </div>
<form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(profileForm.value)">
  <div class="form-group"
    [ngClass]="{'has-error':!profileForm.controls['name'].valid && profileForm.controls['name'].touched}"
    >
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" 
    [formControl]="profileForm.controls['name']"
    [(ngModel)] = 'name' name = 'name'
    >
  </div>

  <div class="form-group"
    [ngClass]="{'has-error':!profileForm.controls['email'].valid && profileForm.controls['email'].touched}"
    >
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" 
    [formControl]="profileForm.controls['email']"
    [(ngModel)] = 'email' name = 'email'
    readonly
    >
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" 
          [disabled]="!profileForm.valid 

                      || !(profileForm.controls['name'].dirty
                      || profileForm.controls['email'].dirty
                        )
                      || updateSucc

          ">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

The variable `updateSucc` is the flag.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the form, when first shows up, may contain some content (let's call this ORIGINAL-CONTENT).
How should the app behave when the user changes the form data in a valid way (so that the button gets enabled) and then changes back again and resets the ORIGINAL-CONTENT?

If in this case the button must be disabled, then you need to link the `[disabled]` attribute to a method that compares the ORIGINAL-CONTENT (which must be stored in a variable in `ngOnInit`) with the current content of the form.

Otherwise I would keep your implementation (maybe changing the name of your variable flag from *updateSucc* to *submitButtonDisabled*) and would set the value of the flag to true with an `onChange()` method triggered by the onChange event of the form.

I hope this helps